# PHP - Displaying SweetAlert modal popup upon successful registration (AJAX)

Tags: php, ajax, registration

I'm wanting to make it so that when my ajax code returns no errors, I get the modal. All my code is working perfectly, I just need to know how to make the modal popup once there are no errors. I have a ajax success: function but I'm not sure how this piece of code would work because at the moment, it only works when a button is clicked.

I'm using the SweetAlert JS files

**My code :**

***The working modal when button is clicked:***

```
  <script>
  !function(e){ "use strict";
   var t = function(){};
   t.prototype.init = function() {
      e("#sa-success").click(function() {
        swal("Registration Successful","Your registration was successful! Check your email and click on your activation link to be able to access your account.","success")
      }
        )
  },e.SweetAlert=new t,e.SweetAlert.Constructor=t}(window.jQuery),function(e){"use strict";e.SweetAlert.init()}(window.jQuery);
</script>
```

***My AJAX registration code I want to make the modal popup once msg = ' ' :***

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {

    jQuery.validator.addMethod("noSpace", function(value, element) { 
     return value.indexOf(" ") < 0 && value != ""; 
  }, "Spaces are not allowed");

            $("#registered_form").submit(function() {

                if ($("#registered_form").valid()) {
                    var data1 = $('#registered_form').serialize();
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "inc/pgs/register.php",
                        data: data1,
                        success: function(msg) {
                            console.log(msg);
                            if(msg == '') {
                                //setTimeout("window.location.href='login.php';",4000);
                            } else {
                                $("#result").html('<div class="alert alert-danger"><button type="button" class="close"></button>' + msg +'</div>').slideDown(100);
                                window.setTimeout(function()
                                {
                                    $(".alert").fadeTo(500, 0).slideUp(500, function(){
                                        $(this).remove(); 
                                    });
                                }, 3000);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

All sorted. I had to see the SweetAlert manual to see how it works. I should've checked before.

I just had to use :

```
swal("Registration Success!", "Your registration was successful! Check your email and click on your activation link to be able to access your account.", "success");
```